# Minimal Possible Ordinal for a Cardinal

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing

For a given $\aleph_\alpha$, what is the minimal ordinal possible such that $|\beta| = \aleph_\alpha$?  More precisely, assume we have a model $N$ of ZFC. $N$ could be an extension of many different models. We have the class of ordinals, which is absolute. Some ordinals in $N$ could be equal to $\omega_1^M$ for some $N = M[G]$, but definitely not $(\omega + 2)^N$ for example. Obviously, there is a minimal ordinal in $N$, which could have been $\omega_1$ in a base model. How do we know which one it is? And for $\omega_\alpha$ in general?

In some way it feels like this ordinal is very "characteristic" of this cardinal, so I wonder if this concept has a name. And what can we say in general about this ordinal?

Comment: Assume we have a model of ZFC. We have the class of ordinals. Belonging to this class is absolute. Some ordinals we can force for example to be equal to $\omega_1$. But we definitely can't do this for $\omega + 13$. Obviously, there is a minimal ordinal in the original model, which CAN be forced to be equal to $\omega_1$ in the new model. How do we know who it is?

Comment: A trivial lower bound is $\omega_\alpha^L$, but I think this is not always tight.  I suspect that this $\beta$ is in some ways less "characteristic" of the cardinal than it is of the particular model $N$.  It is also not obvious that it is definable within the model (a priori, defining it requires quantifying over classes $M$).

Comment: I have to admit that I don't fully understand the question.